# pyuic4 Import error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using **PyQt-Py3.3-x64-gbl-4.9.5-1** package on a **Windows7 64bit** machine.  I'm just trying to get start with PyQt so just created a simply window but when I execute the command to create the code I get this error.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
c:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4>pyuic4 -o FirstApp.py -x FirstApp.ui
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py", line 31, in <module> from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Answer (score 2):

Usage from the command line is(from my machine):

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4>pyuic4.bat inputfile.ui > output.py
```

After the above step add these lines in your output.py file

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form=QtGui.QWidget()
    ui=Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```